# Mathematica: how to have text in multiple colors?

Tags: text, colors, wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to have a manipulate control, something like
`{{wAB, 1, "AB"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}`,
but would like the `A` and the `B` to be different colors, say, `Red` and `Blue`.
I can change the overall color with `Style["AB",Red]`, but haven't been able to get the `A` and the `B` in different colors.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi - I will suggest that you accept one of the 3 answers below. It is also so that future users can see which answer actually worked the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you mean like this?

```
Manipulate[
 wAB,
 {{wAB,1,Row[{Style["A", Red], Style["B", Blue]}]},0,1,Appearance->"Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]

and if you prefer to define the decoration part separately (which can be useful for larger and more complicated controls) and reference it in controls later on (like declaring a variable, sort of, but it is a macro actually) and reuse it for different controls, then you can use `With`, like this

```
Manipulate[wAB,

 Evaluate@With[

   {myStyle = Row[{Style["A", Red], Style["B", Blue]}]},

   {{wAB, 1, myStyle}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}

   ]
 ]
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed, thanx much.  I was close, but was missing the Row, so the text came out truncated. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Although it is safer to do styling with `Style` you can actually color the characters of the string directly using the Format menu or keyboard shortcuts, and *Mathematica* will preserve it in the dynamic control:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for that, Mr.Wizard.  Even if less safe, it's good to know for a quick try out of matching or clashing styles.  Cheers!

Comment: @Mr.W what's the keyboard shortcut to colour something red? Also, install [this](https://github.com/tms/stack-utilities/blob/master/stack-utilities-mathematica-prettify.user.js). It's pretty neat!

Comment: @yoda Alt-R-X-R (in sequence, not at once).  With the script I get no highlighting at all; the default is removed and nothing replaces it.  I am using Firefox 9.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've had issues in Firefox too, but it works beautifully in Chrome.

Comment: Also, that shortcut doesn't work on a mac :( Hey, we're even now — I gave you something that didn't work on your browser and you gave me something that didn't work on my machine :D

Answer (score 0):

If vertical position is x, you must print one letter on x, then count width (w) and print next letter with another color on the new position x+=w.